# How to build opencv_contrib into existing opencv folder?

Tags: opencv

I know it's all described [here](https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib), but it's not clear to me what and where exactly should I build this opencv_contrib source.

Let's assume I've installed OpenCV 3.2 from [official download site](http://opencv.org/downloads.html) and after extracting it looks like this:

[image]

Now, step two:

> select the opencv source code folder and the folder where binaries will be built

which one is the source folder? Should I have it in my OpenCV installation folder or do I need to get it from somewhere else? And where should I build it? Is it, in my case, `/Documents/OpenCV/opencv/build`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What I usually do is to build OpenCV from source directly but it should be more or less the same with the pre-built archive.

With CMake-gui tool:

- *where is the source code:* the directory that contains the OpenCV source code and that contains the `CMakeLists.txt` file (in your case, the `sources` folder in the screenshot).
- *where to build the binaries:* the directory of your choice (in your case the `build` directory or another directory if you want)
- in CMake, the flag `OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH` should point to the `modules` directory of the contrib source.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly how it should be described there

Comment: But, although build was finished succesfully, I can't find FaceRecognizer class which should be in opencv_contrib project. Do you know anything about it?

Comment: You can find `cv::face::FaceRecognizer` in the [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/3.2.0/dd/d65/classcv_1_1face_1_1FaceRecognizer.html).

Comment: Well explained answer!

Answer (score 0):

my build:

```
cd ~/opencv
mkdir build
cd build

cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local -DOPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=../../opencv_contrib/modules  .. 
make -j7
make install
```

../../opencv_contrib/modules is directory of contributed modules directory
.. is opencv source root directory

Answer (score -1):

The OpenCV official download doesn't come with the extra module. You need to download the zip file or clone it using git to your source directory from [OpenCV repository](https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib), e.g. `/Documents/OpenCV/opencv/opencv_contrib` in your case. Then, in CMake, set `OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH` points to `/Documents/OpenCV/opencv/opencv_contrib/modules`.

The `FaceRecognizer` is under the `face` module of the OpenCV Contribute.